# Display contents of array with <br> tags

Tags: php

How can I display or echo this array.  What I am trying to do is display this array with `<br>` tags on a line.  For example:

```
one/two:3
one/four/0:5
one/four/1:6
one/four/2:7
eight/nine/ten:11
```

below is my code

```
$array = array(
    "one/" => array( 
            'two/' => array(
                ':3',
            'four/' => array( 
                '0' => ':5',
                '1' => ':6',
                '2' => ':7'
            )
        )
    ),
    "eight" => array( 'nine', 'ten', ':11' )
);
foreach ( $array as $keys ) {
    echo $keys . '<br />'; 
}
```

Is my `foreach()` correct?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want the keys from your array, you need

```
foreach($array as $key => $val)
// or
foreach(array_keys($array) as $key)
```

As well, foreach does not do multidimensional looping. - your loop would only bring back the "one" and "eight" entries, and not any of the sub-entries.